# Why do C# System.Char methods for Unicode property tests have two overloads?

Tags: c#, unicode, char

In the [methods of System.Char](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char_methods(v=vs.110).aspx), we see two methods for checking if a character is a symbol:

```
public static bool IsSymbol(string s, int index)
public static bool IsSymbol(char c)
```

and likewise for other property tests: IsLower, IsLetter, etc.

Why is there this duplication? Is there any reason to prefer `Char.IsSymbol(s, idx)` over `Char.IsSymbol(s[idx])`?

Comment: Better handling of utf16 surrogate pairs could be a possible reason to take a string I imagine.

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl [Yup, that's it](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/charunicodeinfo.cs). It uses GetUnicodeCategory, which uses InternalGetUnicodeCategory, which uses InternalGetCategoryValue, which does UTF16-to-UTF32 conversion, which could result in decoding of surrogate pairs.

Comment: @TravisJ not if there's an objective reason why one could be preferred.

Comment: @RaymondChen: if you could make that an answer, I think that would do nicely.

Comment: Alright, fair enough.

Comment: Looks like Raphael is correct: https://dotnetfiddle.net/JFMrey . The docs ought to describe this behavior. It's also amusing that a character can be classified as both a high surrogate and a letter.

Comment: @ridiculous_fish: that is not exactly what your code is showing -- `Char.IsLetter(s, 0)` correctly identifies the *whole character* as a letter. `Char.IsHighSurrogate(s, 0)`, unlike all the other functions, actually does only consider the one character at the indicated position, and that character is a surrogate half. `Char.IsLetter(s[0])` returns `false` since the surrogate half is not a letter.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Not sure what you mean by "whole character," but Char.IsLetter decodes a code point, while Char.IsHighSurrogate acts on the code unit. This difference doesn't seem to be documented anywhere, least of all in the method names. That's why one might do a double-take on my code.

Comment: That Unicode requires one or two char to encode a codepoint it a very correct argument when you write C# code.  It isn't the only one, some language designers figured out that utf16 was problematic long before C# came around and decided to support System.Char weakly, requiring the programmer to use the string overload.  Like the language every C# programmer loves to dislike, it shall not be named :)

Answer (score 12):

At the surface both overloads appear to be functionally the same, however drilling down to the call to `InternalGetUnicodeCategory` will reveal that they result in calls different overloads of `CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCateogry`.

The `string,int` overload ends up running through a UTF32 conversion via `InternalConvertToUtf32` prior to calling the same single `char` `InternalGetUnicodeCategory` function.  This accounts for the possibility of decoding Surrogate Pairs in a UTF16 encoded character.

```
   internal static UnicodeCategory InternalGetUnicodeCategory(String value, int index) {
        Contract.Assert(value != null, "value can not be null");
        Contract.Assert(index < value.Length, "index < value.Length");

        return (InternalGetUnicodeCategory(InternalConvertToUtf32(value, index)));
    }
```

[Check out the Conversion implementation here if you want.](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/charunicodeinfo.cs,157fd6c546ef3fa9,references)

Why does this matter you may ask?  Well the answer to that is that .Net supports Text Elements.  Microsoft states:

[MSDN Documentation on Unicode Support for Surrogate Pairs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8k5611at(v=vs.100).aspx)

> A text element is a unit of text that is displayed as a single character, called a grapheme. A text element can be a base character, **a surrogate pair**, or a combining character sequence.

While I do not believe the `IsSymbol` function and its relatives can decode Graphemes or combining character sequences, the reason for the callout to Text Elements is that they **can** be defined as a surrogate pair, and as such would need to be decoded via the `string,int` overload of `IsSymbol(), IsLetter()` etc...

What this means is that passing a surrogate pair via the `char` overload would return the wrong result because the character in the string *could* be a surrogate pair.  You cannot assume that a 16-bit encoding represents a single character, and passing the string's character at said index would make that assumption.

Because surrogate pairs can be represented in a string in .Net, it would reason that if you are dealing with a string that *could* contain one of these, the `IsSymbol(string s, int index)` overload would be more appropriate in order to cover the case where one of these pairs was present.

A specific example where the results differ is

```
string s = char.ConvertFromUtf32(128204); // ""

Debug.Assert(char.IsSymbol(s[0]) == char.IsSymbol(s, 0)); // Fails
```

Comment: Updated with a more concise and poignant answer... hopefully :)

Comment: Are you certain that char.IsSymbol() and such operate on combining character sequences? That's even more surprising. Based on the previous discussion I would expect them to operate just on code points (i.e. only decode surrogate pairs).

Comment: I am not certain in the case of combining sequences, however a Text Element is define as a surrogate pair _or_ a combining character sequence, so I'm really just answering their potential reasoning for the overload.  It would be interesting to see if they operate on the sequences as well.

Comment: @ridiculous_fish Unicode character properties are only defined on a per code point basis, so handling of whole combining character sequences/grapheme clusters doesn't make much sense. Also a quick look at the linked conversion function seems to confirm that it only uses the code point through the utf32 conversion. The quote seems more about the general unicode support in C# and not specific to the `IsSymbol()` functions.

Comment: I agree. @EvanL, if you update your answer to reflect this (that `IsSymbol()` and friends decodes surrogates) and remove the discussion of graphemes and text elements, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @ridiculous_fish I added a bit more clarity around utilizing this function to decode surrogate pairs _only_, but left in the definition of Text Element as I believe it to be core to understanding its relevance in .Net.